# Jquery validation plugin stop form submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate

I'm trying to submit data via post and return it back however my jquery validate plugin is submitting the form even though I have a submitHandler function.

I'm using jquery and jquery form validation plugin.

Any ideas why?

```
$( "#signupForm" ).validate({
  rules: {
    email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
    },
    password: {
        required: true
    },
    password_again: {
      required: true,
      equalTo: "#password"
    },
    month: {
        required: true
    },
    day: {
        required: true
    },
    year: {
        required: true
    },
    gender: {
        required: true
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert('boom');
    $('form').find(":submit").attr("disabled", true).attr("value","Submitting...");
    $.post("includes/signup.php", {
        email: $('#email').val,
        password: $('#password').val,
        month: $('#month').val,
        day: $('#day').val,
        year: $('#year').val,
        gender: $('#gender').val,
        city: $('#city').val
    })
    .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: start by using `$('#...').val() `

Comment: gah. that fixed it. thanks man

Comment: Using `.val()` instead of `.val` fixes it because the latter causes a JavaScript error and the plugin is bypassed.  This is a case where paying attention to your console errors would have solved it instantly.